# How to round a number to the nearest hundreath and make that display on a string in c++

Tags: string, visual-c++, double, rounding

I am working on a money program. Currently I am trying to make  a part in the program that displays a list that shows every transaction that was made in the session. My problem is that when I convert the money amount to a string instead of displaying something like 100.35 in when converted to a string it instead displays something like 100.35000000. I was wondering if there was any way I could make the program drop the additional zeros? Here is a sample of how I convert the numbers to a string

```
int main(){

     double samplemoney=100.35;
     string sample="Today we made $";
     string comsample;
     comsample=sample+std::tostring(money)+".";
     cout<<comsample<<endl;
     return 0;

}
```

In my main program this part is handled with a class but as I said earlier it seems like no matter what the money value I put in is it will display a series of zero and I want my program to drop the unnecessary zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have this number:

```
    double number = 190.0391000;
```

If the problem is displaying the value you may use

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << number
```

where f is the number you want to show.

If your problem is having a string with a finite precision you can use sprintf() in the following way:

```
char arr[128];
sprintf(arr,"%3.2f", number);
std::string formattedstring(arr);
```

or in a more C++ oriented way something like this

```
std::stringstream strn;
strn.precision(2);
strn << std::fixed << number;
```

and then you get the string in the following way:

```
std::string formattedstring = strn.str();
```

I attach the full text of program here... tested on my machine:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    float number=100.24324232;
   std::stringstream strn;
   strn.precision(2);
   strn << std::fixed << number;
   std::cout << strn.str() << "\n";
   return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: The main problem I am having with this is I am converting the number to a string then putting it into a vector for later use sorry I forgot to mention that part

Comment: I got an error for the strn saying incomplete type not allowed or something like that

Comment: #include <sstream> @user2340686

Comment: now  it's tell me that its expecting a ; at the period at the std::stringstream strn.precision(3);
part and I'm not missing any semicolon

Comment: look there was a typo in there strn.precision directly attached to strn. I format better the response now. Sorry about that.

Comment: why is that? I copied and pasted the code I tested here. it should work, try it and tell me what is the error you get @user2340686 there is also the main

Comment: @user2340686 try the main I attached here.

Comment: No problem, just for curiosity... where the problem was? @user2340686